# How can I check if this element exists to prevent property of undefinmed error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a jquery error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

I am assuming I have to add a check to my code but it still gives the error. I'm wondering how to add the check properly

jquery:

```
  var topOfElement = $('.references-list-container-outer').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfElement) {
      $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeIn();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Verify that `$('.references-list-container-outer').length` is greater than zero.

Comment: sounds like someone is looking for the element before it exists on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  var element = $('.references-list-container-outer');
  var topOfElement = element.length ? element.offset().top : 0;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfElement) {
      $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeIn();
    }
  });
```

That checks that there is an element first, if there is not an element, it is setting the value to `0`.

If this is a problem because the page hasn't loaded fully before this is being called, you can wrap the code in document ready:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var element = $('.references-list-container-outer');
  var topOfElement = element.length ? element.offset().top : 0;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfElement) {
      $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeIn();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $('.references-list-container-outer');
if(element.length) {
 var topOfElement = element.offset().top;

 $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfElement) {
        $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeOut();
      } else {
        $('.article-nav-spotlight-chylers-page').fadeIn();
      }
    });
}
```